# Creating decorators for class methods

Tags: python, oop, decorator

Evening guys.

I'm working on/practicing OOP and decorators.

I am able to construct decorators with functions however, I am struggling to create a decorator to work with class methods.

For example, below I have created a User class for an account with an online betting shop.

Here is the class and a method:

```
class User:
"""Creates a user betting account"""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, age, funds, city):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.username = username
        self.age = age
        self.funds = funds
        self.city = city

    def place_bet(self, amount):
        self.funds -= amount
        return f"{self.first_name.title()} - You have placed a £{amount} bet. You have £{self.funds} remaining."
```

What I would like to do is create a decorator that checks the users funds against the amount they are trying to bet. If their funds is larger, the method is allowed to run. Otherwise they receive a message stating they haven't got the funds.

I know I could just place a conditional statement in the method itself but for the purpose of what I am working on and practicing, I would like to achieve this with a decorator.

I have tried something like this:

```
def check_funds(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args[0] < self.funds:
            return "You do not have the funds to place this bet"
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I have tried different variations of this decorator but cannot seem to get it to work. I often get the NameError as "name 'self' has not been defined." even when constructed inside of the class after the **init** method.

I am also unsure if it would be best to construct this decorator inside or outside of the class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Don't return a string containing an error message; that puts the burden of figuring out whether the method succeeded or not on the caller. Raise an exception instead.

Comment: Because methods are *derived from* functions, you have to keep in mind that you are decorating a function, not a method, and so the wrapper has to remember that `args[0]` is `self`, not the first "real" argument.

Comment: Decorators aren't really magic; it's just syntactic sugar for a function call. Like any other function, the decorator has to be defined with what it will be applied to in mind.

Comment: how is `check_funds` supposed to decorate and what? The class or `place_bet`?

Comment: decorate place_bet - Sorry, forgot to specify.